# GMapRoute is throwing NullReferenceException and thus unable to draw routes

Tags: c#, google-maps, gmap.net

I'm using Gmap.Net.WindowsForm but GMapRoute is null and is not drawing routing, GMapRoute gives an error.
    GMapRoute routes = new GMapRoute(direction.Route, "routes");
System.NullReferenceException I get error and Gdirection direction was null I get error

```
GMapOverlay routeshow = new GMapOverlay("yeni rotasyon");
end = new PointLatLng(37.790658, 28.014990);
first = new PointLatLng(37.790658, 29.014990);
//Rotasyon Belirleme
GDirections direction;
var route = GMapProviders.GoogleMap.GetDirections(out direction, first, end, false, false, false, false, false);
GMapRoute routes = new GMapRoute(direction.Route, "routes");
routeshow.Routes.Add(routes);
gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(routeshow);
gMapControl1.Zoom = gMapControl1.Zoom + 1;
gMapControl1.Zoom = gMapControl1.Zoom - 1;
```

Comment: Do you get an error? What is it.

Comment: yes,             GMapRoute routes= new GMapRoute(direction.Route, "routes");
System.NullReferenceException I get error and direction was null I get error

Comment: so I cant draw route

Comment: well, how do i do

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it but try to use

```
new GMapRoute(direction.Route, "route")
```

Instead of

```
new GMapRoute(direction.Route, "routes")
```

Comment: I was looking at http://www.independent-software.com/gmap-net-tutorial-routes.html and they use "MapRoute route" instead of your "var route", worth a try I guess

Comment: I tried it now, but it doesn't Gmaproute gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

The constructor you are using is:

```
    public GMapRoute(IEnumerable<PointLatLng> points, string name)
        : base(points, name)
    {

    }
```

As found in greatmaps\GMap.NET.WindowsForms\GMap.NET.WindowsForms\GMapRoute.cs

I don't see a problem here, I think the problem is with the first parameter here can you check if you are actually getting data. This should resolve the issue.